# One of my activities exits prematurely when SDK > 10, works properly if SDK <= 10

Tags: android, debugging

My program started to fail under SDK 4.0.4, but works on SDK 2.3.3, which doesn't make sense.

The basic flow is:

- First Activity starts remote service and then calls second activity
  on a button click
- The second activity binds to the service, and then exits, with
  nothing in logcat to explain why it happened.

This is what I see, after the service was started:

```
04-15 09:13:46.614: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): Setting a new request for location updates
04-15 09:13:46.661: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): saveProximityAlert - used GPS
04-15 09:13:46.669: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): saveProximityAlert - used network
04-15 09:13:46.677: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): saveProximityAlert - used GPS
04-15 09:13:46.681: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): saveProximityAlert - used network
```

This happens in the second activity:

```
04-15 09:13:47.044: I/MapViewActivity(7039): OnResume: mapView loaded = true
04-15 09:13:47.083: I/MapActivity(7039): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
04-15 09:13:47.196: I/ErrandMapActivity(7039): onServiceConnected
04-15 09:13:47.196: I/ErrandMapActivity(7039): registering callback
04-15 09:13:47.200: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): registerCallback
04-15 09:13:47.200: I/ErrandMapActivity(7039): onResume - binding succeeded
```

Then I see this, which comes from the service, trying to send information to the second activity (which has already exited):

```
04-15 09:13:49.142: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): Sent location changed callback
04-15 09:13:49.142: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): Sent route changed
04-15 09:13:49.142: I/ErrandAssistantService(7015): geoPoint set
```

So, the activity had bound to the service, and then later the service sends back data to the activity, but that activity has already exited.

If I set this to be higher than 10 then it crashes, otherwise it works fine:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

So, how do I troubleshoot that having a higher SDK version crashes the application with no exception, and it doesn't go through `onStop` or `onDestroy`?

In the second activity I have this, which wasn't called, so however it exits appears to be abnormal.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
    super.onStop();
}
```

If I have the SDK version set to 17, but the phone is SDK 2.3.3 then it doesn't crash, but that would appear to be the same as when I set the version of the SDK to be 10 and the phone is version 4.0.4.

I also tried the second activity where it doesn't bind to the service, but the same behavior was observed, so it appears not to be related to the remote service.

I also had the service run in the same process as the activity, to see if I could get any debugging information, but that also didn't give me any additional information.

I don't like having to set the SDK version to be so low, but I needed to get a new update out, and this was the only solution that appears to work.